# OpenCV 2.4.5 installation issue

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2008, computer-vision

I installed MS Visual Studio 2008 on my  windows 8(64-bit) OS. And , then downloaded OpenCV 2.4.5 from the following link.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.5/

After that, I extracted the files and then set the  environment variables accordingly.
I tried running a very simple OpenCV project in order to see whether or not OpenCV has been installed properly.

There's an error saying "fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'".

Is this due to any incompatibility issues ???

Comment: you probably downloaded pre-compiled opencv for 32-bit environment, but you are trying to link your x64 environment to it. another reason could be that you dont have a 64bit compiler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246588.aspx. try to change your project environment settings to x86, or download pre-compiled opencv for x64, also check if you have a x64 compiler.

Comment: Perfect answer, @C.CanberkBacı.. Prasadika - make sure you are trying to link against the x64 libraries and that your project is trying to create x64 binaries of your project (see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)).

Comment: Hi ! Thank You both for the replies. Is there a way to check whether a given OpenCV file is 32-bit or 64-bit ?

Comment: Simply, by looking inside the build folder there are two sub-folders. One specifing the x86 arcgitecture and another one specifing the x64 architecture. Otherwise probably by the link erros.

Comment: Both x86 and x64 folder are there inside the build folder. That means, the version I've installed have support for 64 bits...ryt ? When setting the environment variables and everything, I made sure that I mentioned it like x64 (system architecture) and vc9 (the compiler)....What can be the reason behind this error then ? I'm totally lost

Comment: Are tou linked with the x64 libs included in x64 folder? Also If I understand what you said, yes you must do the appropriate configurations into your VS2008 solution to x64.